# Scala: Function argument Int or Double, how to make it generic?

Tags: scala, generics

I'm almost sure there is already an answer, but being a beginner in Scala I cannot find it.

So, I've made a `power` function of two arguments:

```scala
def power(x: Double, n: Int): Double = {
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def go(acc: Double, i: Int): Double = {
    if (i == 0) acc
    else go(acc * x, i - 1)
    }

  go(1, n)
}
```

If I then calculate `power(2, 3)`

```scala
  println(
    power(2, 3)
  )
```

I get `8.0`, which is OK, but it would be better to have just `8` if the first argument is `Int`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can use the [`Numeric`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html) [**typeclass**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html). This is a common question, you can find more information on with those hints.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks for the links. It would be very nice though if you could write the solution, I'm not sure that I fully understand the docs.

Comment: If one of the operands is Double then the result of the operation will be Double. So, my take is that the approach here is toward formatting of the result when there is no decimal digit.

Comment: @dexter2305 Of course, this will solve the problem here, but my example is simplified on purpose, I'd like to have a more general solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Numeric](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html)

```
def power[T](x: T, n: Int)(implicit num: Numeric[T]): T = {
  import num._
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def go(acc: T, i: Int): T = {
    if (i == 0) acc
    else go(acc * x, i - 1)
    }

  go(fromInt(1), n)
}

power(2, 3) // 8: Int
```

The magic of type class

Comment: Strangely, it still prints `8.0`. I just copypasted your code into my IntelliJ Idea.

Comment: You can use `[T : Numeric]` & `import Numeric.Implicits._` instead. I think that looks nicer. Also, it would be better to use `implicitly[Numeric[T]].one` instead of `fromInt(1)`.

Comment: @EugeneBarsky See here: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/6acdwpL1TtO9ummIXPwTCQ It prints the correct result. Check your other code, it might do a conversion to Double somewhere. You can also test it in Scala console.

Comment: @texasbruce Thanks, now it works for me as well, after I put it in a separate file. Probably some other statements in the package influenced the result.